# Преобразовать id в название Страны

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть две таблицы. 1 таблица. country, там есть два столбца id и country name и вторая таблица city там 3 столбца id, country_id и city_name. Проблема в том что при выборе странны идет подзагрузка городов, город записывается название, а Странна только id, как можно преобразовать что бы Странна записывалась не id , а название странны.

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="сom">

<select name="country" id="country" class="selectindex">
<option>Выберите страну</option>
<?php
$result= $bd->query("SELECT id,country_name from country order by country_name");
while ($country = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>
<option value="<?=$country['id']?>"<?php if ($myrow2['country']==$country['id']) echo 'selected="selected"';?>><?=$country['country_name']?></option>

<?} ?>
</select>
<div class="textinfoedit">Город</div>
<select name="city" id="city" class="selectindex">
<option>Выберите город</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Дальше идет загрузка из cities.php

```
<?php
include "../bd.php";
$country=$_POST['country'];
$result=$bd->query("SELECT id,city_name FROM city where id_country='$country'");
while ($city = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>
<option value="<?=$city['city_name']?>"><?=$city['city_name']?></option>";
<?
}
?>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объедините две таблицы в запросе:

```
SELECT c1.id, c1.city_name, c2.country_name FROM city c1 JOIN country c2 ON c1.id_country = c2.id WHERE id_country='$country'
```

Comment: @ua6xh Спасибо вам большое.

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).